# Remove "Seizure warning" from Microsoft Store productivity app?

Tags: windows-store

We have a productivity app in the Microsoft (Windows) Store.  Been available for years.  There is nothing about it that flashes or has any other stimuli that might cause a seizure.

QUESTION: how does one remove the "Seizure Warning", specifically "Photosensitive seizure warning" that appears in this app's Store Page under "Additional Information" (see red circled text in picture below)?

[image]

Thank you!

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/publish/store-policies#certification-appeal-process

Answer (score 2, accepted):

reportap@microsoft.com team on Oct 20, 2022 emailed me to say ...

"The seizure warning is a default waning applied to all apps in the MS Store front. We cannot remove it."